# 6 channel PWM with 2 - 5 kHz frequency

Tags: pwm, frequency

Is it possible to set all 6 PWM frequencies to a value between 2 and 5 kHz?

I've read that the base frequency for pins pins 5 and 6 is 62500 Hz.
And the divisors for the pins 5 and 6 are only this ones: 1, 8, 64, 256, and 1024.

The closest I can get is 7.812,5 Hz with the 8 divisor. Are there any other possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I haven't choosed yet. My first attempt was to do it with the Raspberry, but the suggestion was to use Arduino. So I found this example: https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PwmFrequency/

Comment: So I know it's goin to be an Arduino, but not exactly which model, because I didn't knew which are capable of my requirements in my question. If this sooo unclear to you, then go on and vote.

Comment: ok, since you are talking about arduino for sure, I am removing the vote to close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your mentioning 62.5 kHz as the base frequency for
pins 5 and 6, I assume you are talking about an Arduino Uno or
something similar.

If you set the timer 0 to phase correct PWM mode (which is how the
Arduino core configures the other timers), then its base frequency is
about 31.373 kHz (`F_CPU`/510). With the prescaler set
to 8, you get a PWM frequency of about 3.922 kHz on pins
5 and 6.

Note that you can set all three timers in this mode and have 6 PWM
channels at this frequency. But note also that by reconfiguring
Timer 0 you loose all the standard Arduino timing functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are there any other models which are better suited for this? But nevertheless, this is quite helpfull. Thank You!

Comment: @WaKai: A Mega has way more timers. On the other hand, if you don't need the Arduino timing functions, the Uno could do the job fine, and the Mega would be overkill.

Comment: Ah, I see. Clock speed: 16 MHz divided by 510 in phase correct mode for the ~32 kHz base frequency. Neat :-)

As far I can think ahead, I won't need any more timers. So the UNO should be perfect.